# Were the alleged CIA attempts to set up an economic spy ring in Japan in the 1980s disclosed in the Japanese press at the time?

Tags: united-states, japan, espionage, press

According Brad Williams' book *Japanese Foreign Intelligence*, which also has a chapter (#2) on CIA's activities in spying on Japan, the CIA tried their hand at economic & tech spying on Japan in the mid-1980s, by setting up a ring of agents under non-diplomatic cover, as business people. However the [PSIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Security_Intelligence_Agency) is said to quickly have uncovered this in part due to poor spycraft by the Americans (including unsecured comms), and so the CIA agents were apparently withdrawn.

Williams doesn't say anything about whether the Japanese made public any of this at the time. (He does cover a lot more the 1982 IBM case, in which the FBI set up a sting operation on two Japanese corporations trying to acquire some IBM trade secrets, and which was widely covered in the US and Japanese press at the time.) Williams source for the info on CIA's attempts at economic spying in Japan is a book in Japanese (alas) Sato Masaru and Koh Young Choul, *Kokka Joho Senryaku*, Tokyo: Kodanash, 2007--which even if I'd manage to get my hands on, I'd not be able to read myself. So, did the Japanese press mention any of this at the time, i.e. that PSIA uncovered CIA's attempts to do some economic spying on Japan? Or was it essentially kept under wraps, for the sake of good relations (despite the publicity in the IBM case)?

Comment: So, it seems this all goes back to one source you can't verify. Do you have anything else to support whether this actually happened?

Comment: I don’t know if this is the same Sato Masaru as in the book, but if it is, I'd take these claims with a grain of salt: https://fpif.org/ideas_identity_and_ideology_in_contemporary_japan/

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what is the presumed connection between the PSIA and the Japanese press?  Is the assumption that the press penetrated the PSIA, that the PSIA used the press as a tool, or that they were part of the same  entity?  Did the PSIA generally leak operational details to the Japanese press, or was there a strategic incentive to jeopardize future operations by leaking this information?

Comment: @Spencer: lol, didn't occur to me the author would be so... famous. Give his ultra-nationalism I'm inclined to think the story is invented. Stil Williams is otherwise a well-respected academic, who's  published in academic journals on this (before the book). I'm surprised he wasn't more skeptical of that source/story.

Comment: BTW, most of that chapter Williams sources from declassified CIA archives, but those declassifications (regarding Japan) stop around the 60's.

Comment: @Spencer - Certainly the story doesn't really pass the smell test. If anyone knows what they're doing spycraft-wise, its the CIA, and Japan seems a low-priority target for them in a world full of threats. Conversely, one could easily see a nationalist wanting to spread a story where their own badass national intelligence agency made the world's most famous intelligence agency look relatively foolish.

Comment: @T.E.D.: oh, you're wrong there. CIA files shows they had a bunch of Japanese politicians on their payroll (Taketora Ogata, Nobusuke Kishi). This is covered in the Western press too. It's just that the CIA normally doesn't do economic spying, which made the other story suspect. And the lack of detail. The CIA files have plenty, this other story was pretty vague. The CIA was interested in keeping at bay both the more pro-Soviet faction of the LDP (Hatoyama's) and the JSP. The CIA both payed slush money and gathered intel on the LDP leaders inclinations etc.

Comment: These individuals were likely classifies as [NOCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(intelligence_gathering)#:~:text=non%2Dofficial%20cover%20(NOC)). See related article at [MotherJones](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/1995/01/cia-crosses-over/) for more background.

Comment: @justCal: sounds like an answer. "Casey saw the Japanese threat as an economic one–and the NOC program as his vehicle to penetrate Japan’s scientific, technological, and commercial institutions. Thirteen NOCs were stationed in Japan in the mid-1980s, including John Quinn." I forgot to mention that the Williams story also dropped the number 13. So, while the immediate sourcing was crap, it was apparently covered elsewhere. Although ultimately the only declassified source seems to be this John Quinn.

Comment: Question as written is focused on coverage in Japanese press. I have no idea where to begin to research articles in Japanese press for the 80s, so just a comment that shows a secondary source that supports the questions contention.

Comment: @justCal: well, that article starts with "Robert Dreyfuss’ revelation that the CIA is engaged in economic espionage (“Company Spies,” June 1994) was covered extensively in Japan, but so far no American newspaper or network has touched the story. " So we know indirectly the Japanese covered it.

Comment: Found another US coverage of it https://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,982540-3,00.html His fuller name if John F. Quinn. OTOH that other story doesn't mention PSIA. So it seems only Dreyfuss covered that bit.

Comment: @Fizz I'm sure you know the drill by now: any details like this should be edited in to the question body.

Comment: @Fizz - It was indeed the economic angle that perked my ears up. There's probably a lot more of that going on now, but during the Cold War not so much. What of that was done I'd imagine was concentrated on communist countries.